# How to include PHP files in plugins the correct way

Tags: plugin-development, functions

My problem is when on the main plugin file I include a PHP file something like this:

```
include(WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/wordpress-group-buying/ipn/paypal-ipn.php');
// or
include_once(WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/wordpress-group-buying/ipn/paypal-ipn.php');
// or
require(WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/wordpress-group-buying/ipn/paypal-ipn.php');
// or
require_once(WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/wordpress-group-buying/ipn/paypal-ipn.php');
```

and on that file I have a call to a WordPress function like:

```
add_action('hook', 'callback');
```

and I get:

> Fatal Error: Call to undefined function add_action()

Now before you say "use `if(**function_exists**('add_action')){`" if I use that then it just doesn't work.

### The questions:

- What would be the correct way to do that?
- What are the difference between `include`, `include_once`, `require` and when do I use witch?

Comment: you're doing something wrong if you get that message. Make sure you include any files before you start running functions from these files

Comment: thats no it, the calls are within the files i'm including!

Comment: lol, now I see `WP_PLUGIN_URL` in your code above :)

Comment: Put very simply you can only include() files via a filepath and not a URI.

Comment: This Codex article (probably written after you asked your question) is quite helpful: http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

Comment: Are you doing this in a PHP file that's being used as an AJAX endpoint, or a form handler? You should **never** make direct calls to PHP files inside WordPress themes or plugins. Also including URLs doesn't work, if it did you'd have a massive security problem, and terrible performance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First , thank you to everyone who answered,

My problem was calling the included files with full url that way they don't go through WordPress. and that happened because as i stated on the question i was calling them from the main plugin file. so the fix ended up using:

```
include_once('/ipn/paypal-ipn.php');
```

i read about at the [WordPress support](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-to-undefined-function-add_action-2?replies=3).
and again thanks for answering!

Comment: Can you please reconsider to mark this answer (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/32002/123092)  as accepted one?

Answer (score 107):

Coming in late to this party, but here's the "WordPress" way: use [`plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path), e.g.:

```
<?php
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'ipn/paypal-ipn.php');
?>
```

Note that the function **does** return the **trailing slash** for the filepath.

Comment: Note that by using `__FILE__` it will output relative to the current file you call it from, so if your `include` statement is done from a subdirectory inside your plugin file structure you'll get the subdirectory back too.

Comment: The alternative - if you *NEED* relative paths, is `require_once(plugin_dir_path(__DIR__).'/myfile.inc');`

Answer (score 10):

I looked through a couple of plugins that I previously created to see the diferent ways that I have included extra files inside of plugins and I noticed there are two methods you can use, there are probably more.

### Define your plugin directory

Inside of your plugin have the following definition to define the current plugin location.

**Example code:**

```
define( 'PLUGIN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__).'/' );
```

### Just a straight up include or require

You can simply use; include, include_once, require or require_once inside of your plugin folder by referencing the location like in the below example code. The below example will be based on a file in your root plugin directory including another file from within a folder inside of your plugin folder.

Example code:

```
include "classes/plugin-core.php";
```

Comment: relative includes can bring all kinds of nasty unexpected issues.

Answer (score 6):

I end up forgoing the WordPress constructs for includes and use the following:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/filename.php);
```

I don't think it will actually solve your issue, which seems to be a scope issue, but it is the code I use.

As for the difference between include and require:
include will throw a **warning** if the file is not found
require will throw a **fatal error** if the file is not found

include_once and require_once will not include/require the file/code again if it has already been included/required (note that as far as I can tell, this is only for a specific file in a specific directory).

Answer (score 6):

> **Include**
>
> The include() statement includes and evaluates the specified file.
>
> **Include Once**
>
> The include_once() statement includes and evaluates the specified
>   file during the execution of the
>   script. This is a behavior similar to
>   the include() statement, with the only
>   difference being that if the code from
>   a file has already been included, it
>   will not be included again. As the
>   name suggests, it will be included
>   just once.
>
> **Require**
>
> require() and include() are identical in every way except how they
>   handle failure. They both produce a
>   Warning, but require() results in a
>   Fatal Error. In other words, don’t
>   hesitate to use require() if you want
>   a missing file to halt processing of
>   the page.
>
> **Require Once**
>
> The require_once() statement includes and evaluates the specified
>   file during the execution of the
>   script. This is a behavior similar to
>   the require() statement, with the only
>   difference being that if the code from
>   a file has already been included, it
>   will not be included again.

The info above is from the PHP documentation, the thing is there is not a correct one, will depend on the need of the code, I do require() on important stuff like functions, but on theme files like footer or the loop I use include_once or include because i can handle the warning and say to the user/visitor that happend an error instead of just a fatal_error

Comment: As the @mtekk say I would recomend you to use tis structure:

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/filename.php);

Answer (score 2):

```
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'ipn/paypal-ipn.php');
```

or

```
define( 'PLUGIN_ROOT_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
include( PLUGIN_ROOT_DIR . 'ipn/paypal-ipn.php');
```

or

```
$plugin_dir_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
include( $plugin_dir_path . 'ipn/paypal-ipn.php');
```

Note : to enqueu .css & .js files `admin_enqueue_scripts` inside plugin use `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )`

```
$plugin_dir_uri = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
wp_enqueue_style( 'plugin-style', $plugin_dir_uri . 'css/plugin-style.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@בניית אתרים:**

When WordPress is loading it defines the `add_action()` function *before* it attempts to load any plugins The fact you are getting the error tells me you are doing something strange or that something is wrong with your WordPress install.

Who are you getting your *"plugin"* to load?  Are you using an `include*()` or `require*()` to load it, maybe in your `wp-config.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a new file inside your working directory, you have to  include it everytime. But try a method to scan your directroy and attach it automatically, not only the php files, Which helps to include php, js and css fiules properly on the both sides( backend, front end).

http://kvcodes.com/2014/05/wordpress-theme-development-include-files-automatically/

Comment: Please add relevant information from the link provided to your answer. Use the link for credit purposes. Please [edit] your question

Answer (score 0):

It may also work:

`include WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/plugin-name/ipn/paypal-ipn.php';`