# Wordpress functions give fatal error in included php file

Tags: plugins

First, my problem is similar to [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7398/how-to-include-php-files-in-plugins-the-correct-way). However, the solution posted there doesn't work for me.

I'm creating a plugin that displays a contact form on a page using the Shortcode API.

Plugin folder contents:

- contact.php (main plugin file)
- validate.php (included php file)

The main file has the usual plugin header, and WordPress functions called in it work as expected [i.e: get_permalink()]

The validate.php file is included in contact.php as follows:

```
define ("PLUGIN_PATH", plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
include_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/validate.php';
```

My problem is any WordPress functions called in validate.php will throw a fatal error. PHP functions work as expected, only WordPress functions are throwing a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sanitize_text_field() in /{FULL WEBSITE PATH}/ralrom-contactform/validate.php
```

How should I be including the validate.php file to be able to call WordPress functions from it?

I have tried "require" and "include" variations and all throw the same fatal error.

**Before using multiple files, I had a working version as a single file shown here:**

Orignal working code under a single php file:
http://pastebin.com/qM5aj9qY

Broken code under two php files:
http://pastebin.com/KUCbg6rJ

Comment: Is `include_once` call directly in plugin body? Not nested in any functions? Is it possible something tries to load `contact.php` directly?

Comment: Yes it's directly placed in the plugin body

Comment: Well, whatever is going wrong - it seems to not have made into details you have included so far. Try to elaborate and add to question on what you started with and which changes caused it to break.

Comment: I added two pastebins in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're POSTing the form to the validate.php file directly, so the WordPress code isn't loaded. Instead you need to POST the form to the current URL or the home_url or something like that, and then have the plugin intercept the data and act accordingly, so that the WordPress code is loaded before you use its functions.

Comment: Thank you! At first I wasn't sure how to do this but after fiddling for the past few hours I figured out how to do it and prevent form re-submission.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I figured out that what I was trying to do wasn't exactly possible.

The reason being POSTing data to a php page will send the POST data outside of the WordPress loop or "framework". Therefore the WordPress functions aren't loaded. A way around this is to require the wordpress files that contain the functions you want to use inside your php page, i.e:

```
require_once {path to wordpress wp-includes}/formatting.php;
```

However, I felt this was a dirty way to do things.

Instead, I followed [Otto's suggestion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100130/33064) and intercepted the POST data before WordPress loaded the page by attaching a function to the "init" hook:

```
add_action("init", "intercept_post");
```

The form action is set to the current page and in the intercept_post function I run data validation, send the email and redirect to the same page. This effectively sends the POST data and prevents a page refresh from submitting the data again.