# php "use" not working in template

Tags: php, functions, templates, include, amazon

I am trying to implement code from [this site](https://w3lessons.info/2018/02/07/php-text-to-speech-amazon-polly/) and in the code the following line is causing an error and my page is not loaded --

```
use \Aws\Polly\PollyClient;
```

If I comment the code out then the page loads fine and I get no errors besides that the script I tried to use wont work.

Code seems pretty standard php so im wondering if it's cause it's wordpress and I would need to do something else to be to use - "use" ?

FULL CODE ---

```
//include_once ('/polly/aws-autoloader.php');

require_once ('/polly/aws-autoloader.php');
use \Aws\Polly\PollyClient;

if(isset($_REQUEST['voice']) && $_REQUEST['voice'] != '') {

$voice_id = $_REQUEST['voice'];

} else {

$voice_id="Joanna";

}

if(isset($_REQUEST['text']) && $_REQUEST['text'] != '') {

$text = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['text']));

}

if(isset($_REQUEST['rate']) && $_REQUEST['rate']!='') {

$rate=$_REQUEST['rate'];

} else {

$rate="medium";

}



$is_download = false;


if(isset($_REQUEST['download']) && $_REQUEST['download']==1) {

$is_download=true;

}


$config = [

'version'     => 'latest',
'region'      => 'us-east-1',
'credentials' => [
'key'    => 'MY KEYS',

'secret' => 'MY KEYS',
]

];

$client = new PollyClient($config);
$args = [

'OutputFormat' => 'mp3',
'Text' => "<speak><prosody rate='$rate'>".str_replace("&","&amp;",urldecode ($text))."</prosody></speak>",
'TextType' => 'ssml',
'VoiceId' => $voice_id,
];

$result = $client->synthesizeSpeech($args);
$resultData = $result->get('AudioStream')->getContents();

$size = strlen($resultData); // File size

$length = $size; // Content length

$start = 0; // Start byte

$end = $size - 1; // End byte

if(!$is_download) {

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding:chunked');

header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");

header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");

header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");

header("Content-Length: $length");

echo $resultData;


} else {


header('Content-length: ' . strlen($resultData));

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="polly-text-to-speech.mp3"');

header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');

header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

echo $resultData;

}
```

Comment: Did you try [debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) this? Could be a (very very) old PHP version on the server

Comment: @kero the php version is not old.

Comment: Please debug this a bit further. Without an error message it is just guessing. `/polly/aws-autoloader.php` seems off (see [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7398/how-to-include-php-files-in-plugins-the-correct-way))

Comment: I did and I get this -- `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /var/......`

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33355711), which came up when I searched for your error message: (emphasis mine)

> You cannot use "use" where you are using it.
>
> The "use" keyword is either in front of a class definition to import other classes/interfaces/traits into it's own namespace, or it is inside the class (**but not inside a method**) to add traits to the class.

The `use` has to be outside of the function I presume you are calling it in. Something like this should work

```
<?php

use \Aws\Polly\PollyClient;

// some code

function myfunc() {
    require_once ('/polly/aws-autoloader.php');
    // rest of the code
}
```

It should be no problem that you require the autoloader after the `use` keyword. After all, it only expands `PollyClient` to `\Aws\Polly\PollyClient` when you use it in the code.