# Use a PHP file as action for a form in a WordPress plugin, what's the correct way?

Tags: plugin-development, forms

I'm developing my first "serious" WordPress plugin using Devin Vinson's plugin boiler plate generated with [this generator](https://wppb.me). Now I need to use a PHP file not present in default boilerplate as action attribute value for a form. When the form is submitted and the PHP file executed I get many fatal errors of call to undefined function for every WordPress function that I call in that file...
I already read [THIS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7398/how-to-include-php-files-in-plugins-the-correct-way) and I obviously required the PHP file with `require_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/ccwdpo-submit-question.php';` but I didn't solve my problem...

What's my mistake?

Comment: Move the logic from the PHP file to the function and invoke it after sending the form. `admin_post_{action}` hook is what you need. [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) you will find usage examples.  If something is unclear, ask.

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, you should never use a PHP file as action attribute for a form in WordPress. WordPress already has API for this and you should use this instead. Why? Because it's always better if your app/site has only one entry point (or as few as possible).

And it's always a bad idea to direct any PHP requests directly to wp-content directory - such requests are very often blocked for security reasons.

### So how to do this properly?

Use [`admin-post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) instead.

So in your form change this:

```
<form action="<SOME FILE>" ...
```

to this:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_attr( admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) ); ?>" ...
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myform" />
```

And later in your plugin, you have to register your actions callbacks:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_myform', 'prefix_admin_myform_callback' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_myform', 'prefix_admin_myform_callback' );


function prefix_admin_myform_callback() {
    status_header(200);
    die("Server received '{$_REQUEST['data']}' from your browser.");
    //request handlers should die() when they complete their task
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try soon your solution but I have a doubt: what means "action"="myform" in hidden input field?

Comment: It tells WP, which action should it run to process this request. The "myform" part is then used to register your callbacks - `admin_post_{action}`

Comment: Yeah, I understand but is it correct to use "action" with double quotes as a name for a "not-standard" attribute?

Comment: @icolumbro Aaaa... Sorry for that, it's just a typo - this happens when you write answer on mobile. I've already fixed this - sorry again :)

Comment: I figured it is a typo even reading the codex page but I preferred to ask you to be sure, thank you, now I try!

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: Why this answer is not the Accepted one? It's nice to explain the WordPress implement in the practise and instead of the pure PHP syntax-sugar.